# Javascript/jQuery Scoping and Context Issue when trying to manipulate the "reference" of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I think I am running into a "context" issue and hoping someone can shed some more light on the subject.

I want to remove the source of all images on a page.  I have built an array of objects for each image.  When I hide the source, I want the changes to show up real time without effecting my original object properties.  I want to manipulate the images (on screen) on a click event.

For example:

```
$('#moz_iframe').contents().find("img").each(function(index){
    aryImageObjects.push(new imageObject($(this), $('#iframeHolder')));
}); //end each
```

...

```
function imageObject(objImg, objHolder) {   
    this.objImg = objImg;
    this.imgSrc = objImg.attr('src');
    //this.objImg.replaceWith('hrm'); <-- this works just fine in this context 
}; //end constructor
```

...
but this does not work:

```
$('#imagesOff').click(function(){
    for (i=0; i<aryImageObjects.length; i++) {
        aryImageObjects[i].objImg.replaceWith('hrm');
    };
}); //end imagesOff click function
```

I have also tried building an object method within my original constructor:

```
this.hideImages = function() {
    this.objImg.replaceWith('hrm');
    };
```

...

```
$('#imagesOff').click(function(){
    for (i=0; i<aryImageObjects.length; i++) {
        aryImageObjects[i].hideImages();
    };
}); //end imagesOff click function
```

But that doesn't seem to work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: so you say you want to change the source for that image but keep it's original source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here's what i've come up](http://jsfiddle.net/uLR9y/)

```
$(function() {

    //reference array
    var ref = [];

    (function() {

        //get each image and reference the element and store source
        $('img').each(function() {
            var newImg = {};
            newImg.el = this; //storing the DOM element instead of a jQuery object
            newImg.src = this.src;
            ref.push(newImg);
        });
    }());

    //if the element is clicked, replace using the reference in the array
    $('img').on('click', function() {
        for (i = 0; i < ref.length; i++) {

            //wrap reference in jQuery, and operate
            $(ref[i].el).replaceWith('hrm');
        };

        //img still here even after DOM was replaced
        console.log(ref);
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks so much Joseph, yeah this has been a good lesson in knowing the difference btw. storing the DOM element vs. the reference to the jQuery object.  But it actually turns out that my code wasn't working because I was doing a search and replace through the entire body element to get rid of background attributes (in TDs) and that was essentially restructuring my original DOM.  Thanks so much for your help and insight!